# Is there a way to remove empty cells(commas for empty cells) when writing to csv from pandas python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

For example I have a df as such

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |  |  |
| 1 | 2 |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 5 | 9 | 5 | 3 | 1 |
| 5 |  |  |  |  |  |

when I convert this to csv I get a csv which has ',' for the cells that are blank. IE

```
1,2,3,4,,,
1,2,,,,,
1,5,9,5,3,1
5,,,,,,
```

Is there a way to have it so that I just get the filled in cells and remove the commas with empty cells?
Expected output is:

```
1,2,3,4
1,2
1,5,9,5,3,1
5
```

This is a large dataset with millions of rows and thousands of columns. Hence trying to see if I can remove unnecessary spaces.

Comment: Please format your expected output in a manner that is more readable.

Comment: @j__carlson - Why would you change OP's example in your edit?

Comment: @not_speshal I was unaware that I had.

Answer (score 1):

- `to_csv()` is defined to ensure every column is considered, so empty columns will be delimited
- output `to_csv()` to a buffer then `strip(",")` to remove trailing commas
- output this to a file

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": [1, 1, 1, 5],
        "B": [2.0, 2.0, 5.0, np.nan],
        "C": [3.0, np.nan, 9.0, np.nan],
        "D": [4.0, np.nan, 5.0, np.nan],
        "E": [np.nan, np.nan, 3.0, np.nan],
        "F": [np.nan, np.nan, 1.0, np.nan],
    }
)


with open(Path.cwd().joinpath("special.csv"), "w") as f:
    f.write("\n".join([l.strip(",") for l in df.to_csv(index=False, header=None).split("\n")]))
```